# EF Core generated SQL is quite inefficient in this case, any workaround?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Take such simple entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MainEmail { get; set; }
}

public class Person_Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_Person { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This query:

`db.Person.Where(p => p.Person_Email.Any(c => c.Email == "myemail@email.com") || p.MainEmail == "myemail@email.com").FirstOrDefault();`

gets translated as:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [p].[Id]
FROM [Person] AS [p]

WHERE (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Person_Email] AS [p1]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [p1].[Id_Person]) AND ([p1].[Email] = N'myemail@email.com')) 
    OR ([p].[MainEmail] = N'myemail@email.com')
    )
```

and this is very slow, on my db the profiler says 4347316 reads and a duration of 2568).

I would write the sql as:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [p].[Id]
FROM [Person] AS [p]

join [Person_Email] as pe on p.Id = pe.Id_Person
where p.MainEmail = N'myemail@email.com' or pe.Email = N'myemail@email.com'
```

In this case the profiler says 17448 reads and a duration of 300.

I wonder if there's a way to optimize this writing the LINQ query in a different way or we can but wait for the ef core team to improve it (I tried ef core 5.0 preview 8 and nothing changed).

Comment: If you have the proper indexes the first query shouldn't be slow.

Comment: write the linq which give you the sql you want: https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/sql-joins-with-csharp-linq

Comment: @GertArnold that the first thing I looked at but I have a NONCLUSTERED INDEX on both Person.MainEmail and Person_Email.Email plus a CLUSTERED INDEX on Person_Email.Id_Person. What else should I add? Also, the app in running in production on SQL Azure for long now and its ML never suggested another index there

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var person = (from a in db.Person
              from b in db.Person_Email.Where(c => c.Id_Person == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
              where a.MainEmail == "myemail@email.com" || b.Email == "myemail@email.com"
              select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var personemail = db.Person_Email.Where(c => c.Email == "myemail@email.com").FirstOrDefault();

var person = db.Person.Where(c => (personemail == null || c.Id == personemail.Id_Person) || c.MainEmail == "myemail@email.com").FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]

Comment: To get first record. Or same as Single(). What's wrong?

Comment: added screenshot. 3x faster.

Comment: Actually the first LINQ query is close to OP desire. Just replace the manual left outer join `from b in db.Person_Email.Where(c => c.Id_Person == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()` with auto inner join by navigation property `from b in a.Person_Email` and you'll get the desired translation. Whether it is more efficient is another story - IMHO `EXISTS` should be treated as `JOIN` by nowadays CBOs, but that's what OP wants.

Comment: thanks @Asherguru but this won't improve, I would suggest to use Profiler, Stopwatch doesn't work well in such situations